# Error Updating Android Studio 3.0.1 to 3.1.3

Tags: android-studio

This is the dialog I get every time I try to update, please help

[image: Error displayed during update]

Comment: Have you run it as Administrator? Try to stop your Anti Virus before updating.

Comment: I have tried disabling my anti virus and still same result, any other suggestions will be very helpful. I have tried from Android Studio and even manual update